# cannot edit access database using IP but works via localhost

Tags: c#, iis, oledb

I have created an c# dotnetcore project and i host it via IIS. In Addition to that i have an Angular project as frontend. My Database is on a Computer in my Network. When i want to edit my Database i can do it when i run my dotnetcore project via Visual Studio. When i publish it to the IIS i can't edit the database.

how i connect to the database: \\computername\accdb

Im getting the followed error:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005) opened exclusively by another user or no permission

Comment: Have you investigated if another process is currently accessing the database, or if IIS does not have the permissions to access the database?

Comment: how can i find out if my pc has permission to access the database on the other pc?

Comment: If it's in IIS then it's running under an Application Pool account. Check that account has access.

Comment: it should have permission.

Comment: or can you tell me how i find it out (maybe with an example?)

Comment: You used MSAccess for this? Did no one tell you SQLite was a thing? If it was going to be the case that the DB was on another computer, did no one tell you that SQLServer is a thing?

Comment: im doing it for a customer and he another program who defines how to store data

Comment: Oof. I'm not sure I'd have taken that job! So, about talking your customer round so they let you make the decisions about where the data is housed..

Comment: i tried this, but unlucky me it's not possible

Comment: Refer to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/error-80004005-connecting-access-database) about error 80004005. If you want IIS has permission to access database, using `sqllocaldb.exe share xxx` command to share database instance. Add IIS APPPOOL\app pool name to sql sercurity-logins.